# Sum of integers and system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I always wondered but never understood how to solve the following type of equation
$$\begin{matrix}
&{x}+y=35 \\
&x\geq15 \\
&y\geq 15 \\
&(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}
\end{matrix} $$

(I just made up values)
I found the two pairs 
$$(19;16) \;\& \;(17;18)$$
Are they the only solutions ? if they are, how to prove it?

Comment: $$(x, y) = (20, 15), (15, 20){}{}$$ Same is true for the two other values you wrote - you can switch $(x, y)$, so there are a total of six pairs. You can draw a contour plot for this one and see the region of interest.

Comment: pairs are not ordered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write $ x=15+k_1, y =15+k_2$ 
Now substitute these in $ x+y =35 $ 
We get $ k_1 + k_2 =5 $ Now the number of possible values of $k_1, k_2$ corresponds to the possible values of $x$ and $y$ so the number of ways are $ C(n+r-1,r-1) $ Here, in this particular problem $n=5$ and $r=2$, so total ways are $6$.

Comment: To obtain subscripts in math mode, type k_1 between dollar signs.  If you have more than one subscript, put the subscripts in curly braces.   For instance $a_{12}$ is obtained by typing a_{12} between dollar signs.  Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thank you NF Taussig that was much needed!

Answer (score 1):

Given that $\ x\ge 15$, we get that, $\ 35-y \ge 15$ i.e $\ y\le 20$. Since , its given $\ y\ge 15$ . Therefore , possible integral values of $\ y$ belong to the set $ \{\,15,16,17,18,19,20\,\}$

And for each $y$ , there is a unique value of $x=35-y$ that is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

**Graph**!

And also, there are infinitely many rational solutions, however only a finite amount of integer coordinates.

Here is the graph:
[image]

The intersection of the green and blue shaded sections (green-blue section) give you your $x$ and $y$ solutions.